# Insert URL text into database using x-editable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, x-editable

I have a table with inline editing using X-editable and everything is working fine including the value being submitted to the database, but for some reason it will display my echo in the else section.

Here is my PHP code:

```
require("config.php");

$userid = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
$sql = "SELECT fb_url, tw_url, ggl_url FROM social_preferences WHERE user_id = :userID";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":userID", $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();   


$pk = $_POST['pk'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$value = $_POST['value'];

    if(!empty($value)) {
            try // save user selection to the database
              {

                $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE social_preferences SET tw_url = :twurl WHERE user_id = :userID");
                $stmt->bindParam(":userID", $pk, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->bindParam(':twurl', $value);
                $stmt->execute();

                header("Location: admin-social.php"); 
                die("Redirecting to admin-social.php"); 
               }  catch(PDOException $e) { echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); }
    }else {
        echo 'Something went wrong!';
        var_dump($value);
    }
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<a name="tw-url" id="tw-url" data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo ($userid);?>" title="Edit"><?php echo ($result['tw_url']);?></a>
```

Like I said above everything seems to be working but it redirects to a page that will display my echo `Something went wrong!`even though it submitted the value to the DB. I included the var_dump to see if there is a value and that returns NULL. Can someone please help me? Any ideas why it would submit the right value to the database but redirect to my error?

Also, at what point does it send it to the database? I have a table in a form with a save button, but when I open the editable text and submit the new value does it send to the database when I save from the pop-over or when I click the save button in my table form?

Comment: so what MySQL / PDO errors do you get?

Comment: `href`'s are usually associated/executable as a GET and you're passing it as a POST, therefore `if(isset( $_POST['mysocialurl']))` will never be `set`.

Comment: Any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: is there anyone that can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` statement is executing because when your details inserted into DB, you have set a `header` which redirects to the same page, in that case the variable `$value` value set to empty and your `else` statement executes.

The above answer is only valid if you set your `header` to same page.

Comment: I removed the this: `header("Location: admin-social.php");        die("Redirecting to admin-social.php");` from my code and it all seems to be working. Is there any reason why I would need to keep this piece of the code?

Comment: Generally we use `header("Location: filename.php")` when we want to redirect to a different page, but when data posted to same page we should use a variable to know whether our data is submitted or not. For eg. you can replace your `header("Location: ..."); die("...");` code with `$output = "submitted";` and in your HTML code your can use this `$output` variable to validate submission like so:

`if(isset($output) and $output === "submitted") { echo "Data has been submitted"; }`

You can style your output message according to template.

Comment: I tried what you suggested above and it is not working. I have admin-social.php and post.php, admin-social.php displays the html and some other php not related to post.php and post.php is where the `$output` variable is so I am not sure if it is passing the variable to admin-social.php. You did answer my original question so thank you.

Comment: @iamthestreets The above comment is valid when you post your form data to the same page, as you said that your data is going from _admin-social.php_ to _post.php page_, in that case you have to use either `header` or post your data using AJAX, to send AJAX request you can either write core JS or use jQuery for ease.

In my opinion, its better to use AJAX when doing inline editing and update.

Learn jQuery AJAX at [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/)

Learn complete jQuery at [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/30-days-to-learn-jquery)